# Cmake library prefix/suffix

Tags: cmake

I need to link with a third-party pre-built shared library. On Windows, that means linking with `Third_party.lib`, and on Linux/Android, that means linking with `libThird_party.so`. So in the interest of cross-platformness, I tried to write that as:

```
${CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_PREFIX}Third_party${CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
```

Which works fine on Windows, but on Linux/Android, these variables are blank. I get that Linux/Android doesn't have import libraries, but nonetheless these variables being blank is actually a big nuisance. And changing the variables to `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_...` doesn't work either, because even though Linux/Android would then look for lib/.so like I want, Windows will look for .dll, which I don't want.

It seems like I can fix this by populating the import library variables (only on Linux) with values from the shared library variables. But... is this really the best way? I can't possibly be the first person to bump into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you let CMake and its helpers do that job of figuring the right name out. Quite possibly, for your third party library, there's already a `Find<Library>.cmake` script out there.

If there isn't: Here's something taken from `FindUSB.cmake` from [GNU Radio](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindUSB.cmake)

```
if(NOT LIBUSB_FOUND)
  pkg_check_modules (LIBUSB_PKG libusb-1.0)
  find_path(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES libusb.h
    PATHS
    ${LIBUSB_PKG_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    /usr/include/libusb-1.0
    /usr/include
    /usr/local/include
  )

  find_library(LIBUSB_LIBRARIES NAMES usb-1.0 usb
    PATHS
    ${LIBUSB_PKG_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
  )

if(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR AND LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)
  set(LIBUSB_FOUND TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "libusb-1.0 found")
  message(STATUS "Found libusb-1.0: ${LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR}, ${LIBUSB_LIBRARIES}")
else(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR AND LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)
  set(LIBUSB_FOUND FALSE CACHE INTERNAL "libusb-1.0 found")
  message(STATUS "libusb-1.0 not found.")
endif(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR AND LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)

mark_as_advanced(LIBUSB_INCLUDE_DIR LIBUSB_LIBRARIES)

endif(NOT LIBUSB_FOUND)
```

Notice the [`pkg_check_modules`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) directive and the [`find_library`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) directive that take care of giving you the *right* things without you hand-appending suffixes etc.

You'll probably want to add the path you expect your .dll to be to the `PATHS` arguments of `find_path` and `find_library` (those are pointers for CMake to know where to look).

Comment: Thanks. I have a follow-up question. Some of these libraries are downloaded and compiled using ExternalProject, which means they won't exist until build time. That causes a problem when running the initial cmake command, because it can't link with variables that hold a value of NOTFOUND.

Comment: usually, you'd have sub-directories with their own CMakeLists.txt and run include these, and run from there. However, the real world is usually much more complex. Ask a completely new question on StackOverflow with a lot more details :)